# Select from mysql database with c#.net winforms - how to check response?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms

I'm adding a record into remote mysql database and after that I want to check if it's added - So i want to try to select this particular record.

My code:

```
    public void Select(string filename)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM banners WHERE file = '"+filename+"'";

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
```

How to check the response from the server? Or selected records? 
It's c# windows forms app.

Comment: You may use datatable to be filled with the data either by SqlDataReader or SqlDataAdapter. Now just check rowcount over datatable object.

Comment: filename is new added record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void Select(string filename)
{
        string query = "SELECT * FROM banners WHERE file = '"+filename+"'";

        //open connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Get the DataReader from the comment using ExecuteReader
                            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
                while (myReader.Read())  
                { 
                    //Use GetString etc depending on the column datatypes.
                    Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetInt32(0)); 
                } 

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
        }
}
```

Check this URL for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making another round-trip (with additional select) you can expand you insert statement by

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

execute your insert command

```
command.ExecureQuery();
```

and get the ID of the last inserted record.

Have a look at [MySQL Information Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it when you run `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` for `INSERT` statement itself. `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of rows affetced (inserted in your case). So

```
if(command.ExecuteNonQuery()>0)
{
 //inserted
}
else
{
 //Not inserted
}
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executenonquery